# python function that calls functions some with parameters

Tags: python

I have a python script with a generic method that calls functions for every line in a file. This method takes the function to be called as a parameter and arguments (optional) for this function. The problem is that some of the functions that it will call need parameters and others don't.

How would I go about doing this?

Code example:

```
def check_if_invalid_characters(line, *args):
    # process word

def clean_words_with_invalid_characters():
    generic_method(check_if_invalid_characters, *args)

def check_if_empty_line(line):
    # process word

def clean_empty_lines():
    generic_method(check_if_empty_line)

def generic_method(fun_name, *args):
    with open("file.txt") as infile:
        for line in infile:
            if processing_method(line, *args):
                update_temp_file(line)

clean_words_with_invalid_characters()    
clean_empty_lines()
```

Comment: Why? What does this accomplish which just processing them individually would not?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  Zero parameters is a valid thing to pass to a function that takes *args, and you can pass an empty *args to a function that takes zero parameters.

Comment: Why don't you just call twice the `generic_method`: one time for the characters another for the lines?

Comment: @jasonharper You were right. I thought I tested that option before and got an error, but apparently I was wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't an if ,else satisfy your needs? like this :

```
def whatever(function_to_call,*args):
    if(len(arg)>0):
        function_to_call(*args)
    else:
        function_to_call()
```

Comment: That's not necessary (at least in Py2.7). You can simply pass an empty `*args` and it doesn't mind. Also, it should be `*args` for the function call.

Answer (score 0):

You can still pass empty *args to the function that doesn't need them...
If a function only calls another function then you can bypass it, don't you?

```
def check_if_invalid_characters(line, *args):
    # process word using *args
    print(args)


def check_if_empty_line(line, *args):
    print(args)
    # process word and don't use *args (should be empty)

def generic_method(processing_method, *args):
    with open("file.txt") as infile:
        for line in infile:
            if processing_method(line, *args):
                update_temp_file(line)

generic_method(check_if_invalid_characters, foo, bar)
generic_method(check_if_empty_line)
```